# Show sum of efforts for a day in Org-Agenda day title

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

I would like to show sum of efforts for all tasks for a day in Org-Agenda day title. E.g. for a week agenda there would be 7 sums for each of the day, in their respective titles.

I think this could be done somehow by manipulating the `org-agenda-format-date` variable.

By default, this variable points to a builtin function `org-agenda-format-date-aligned`, but I suppose it can be reset to point to a custom function to include the sum of efforts in the date line.

Could you please help me define such a function?

Also, I would like to use a predefined `Effort` value for all tasks lacking the `Effort` property.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question so I'll post as a comment, but a similar effect can be gained from a clocktable, e.g. put a `#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 7 :scope agenda :block thisweek :step day :fileskip0 :formatter :link 2 :indent t :narrow 79 :formula %` `#+END:` then `C-c C-x C-u` inside that clocktable. You can change "thisweek" to "lastweek", tune the level of detail shown with `:maxlevel` etc. That has the advantage that it's only updated when you explicitly ask, as pulling out that effort information can be a little slow.

Answer (score 4):

So far as I know, this is not possible. You can get an effort sum using column view, though only for one day at a time. Set column format as follows:

```
(setq org-columns-default-format "%60ITEM(Task) %6Effort(Estim){:}")
```

Then, when in agenda view, restrict your view to a single day using 'd' and then turn on column view (C-c C-x C-c).

That will get you what you want. Though there seems to be a bug such that this will not work properly if you use more than one agenda file.

Comment: Close, though not exactly,

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by defining a function such as `my/org-agenda-insert-efforts` that inserts the sum of the efforts next to the heading for a particular day after the agenda has been generated. The function only considers scheduled items for a particular day:

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun my/org-agenda-calculate-efforts (limit)
  "Sum the efforts of scheduled entries up to LIMIT in the
agenda buffer."
  (let (total)
    (save-excursion
     (while (< (point) limit)
       (when (member (org-get-at-bol 'type) '("scheduled" "past-scheduled"))
         (push (org-entry-get (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker) "Effort") total))
       (forward-line)))
    (org-duration-from-minutes
     (cl-reduce #'+
                (mapcar #'org-duration-to-minutes
                        (cl-remove-if-not 'identity total))))))

(defun my/org-agenda-insert-efforts ()
  "Insert the efforts for each day inside the agenda buffer."
  (save-excursion
   (let (pos)
     (while (setq pos (text-property-any
                       (point) (point-max) 'org-agenda-date-header t))
       (goto-char pos)
       (end-of-line)
       (insert-and-inherit (concat " ("
                                   (my/org-agenda-calculate-efforts
                                    (next-single-property-change (point) 'day))
                                   ")"))
       (forward-line)))))
```

The function can then be added to `org-agenda-finalize-hook` so that the text is automatically inserted after the agenda has been generated:

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook 'my/org-agenda-insert-efforts)
```

Comment: Works just fine!